# Salesforce LightningQuickAction Not Working as Expected

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

im new in salesforce and need your guidance.

Im creating lightning component as below.

[image]

For this lightning component, im implementing : **force:lightningQuickAction**.

Also there is a button : "**Select Product Item**"

When button pressed, i want to call another component as a popup just like the picture above.
But here is what i get:

[image]

Here is my code:
**Component 1: cmp**:

```
<aura:component controller="OptyProductItemController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    
        // Removed code here

        <lightning:button variant="Brand" class="slds-m-top_small" type="submit" label="Create SO" />
        <lightning:button variant="Neutral" class="slds-m-top_small" label="Select Product Item" onclick="{! c.pickProductItem }" />
    
</aura:component>
```

**Component 1: controller**

```
pickProductItem : function(component, event, helper) {
        var navigateEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
        navigateEvent.setParams({
            componentDef: "c:SelectSalesOrderItem",
            componentAttributes: {
                optyId : component.get("v.recordId")
            }
            //componentAttributes :{ }
        });
        navigateEvent.fire();
    }
```

**Component 2: cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="SelectSalesOrderItemController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="mycolumn" type="Object[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="optyId" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute type="Opportunity_Product_Item__c[]" name="optyProductList"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.fetchOptyProduct}"/>
    
    <lightning:datatable data="{!v.optyProductList }" 
                         columns="{!v.mycolumn}" 
                         keyField="id"
                         hideCheckboxColumn="false" />
</aura:component>
```

Is there any mistake in my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some comments first:**

- If these are new components that you are building, I recommend that you create them as Lightning Web Components (LWC) instead, since Aura is now considered a legacy technology.
- If they need to remain as Aura components, the [documentation for force:navigateToComponent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToComponent/documentation) mentions that this event is deprecated and recommends instead:

  - Implementing the `lightning:isUrlAddressable` interface in the target component.
  - Navigating to the component using `lightning:navigation` component with the `standard__component` page type instead.

For your reference: [Documentation for lightning:isUrlAddressable with examples](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation).

---

**Now to your actual question:**

What you are experiencing is the intended behavior. From the documentation for `force:navigateToComponent` that I linked above:

> When fired from a component embedded in Lightning Experience or Salesforce app, the app creates and renders the target component in the app content area, replacing the current content.

If you want your second component to open as a popup - similar to how the first component is behaving - I would suggest one of the following two options:

**1) Rendering your second component within the first one (component composition)**

You can use aura:if or JS code to decide when to show the second component.

```html
<!--c:yourFirstComponent-->
<aura:component>
    <c:yourSecondComponent/>
</aura:component>
```

**2) Combining both components into a single one**

Simply having your first component contain all the logic needed to perform both operations. The first method is preferable to this one, but this is an alternative.